# Bill of materials configuration selection

Tags: algorithm, user-interface

This is more of an algorithmic/design question

Consider 5-6 items (bolts, frame, gears, etc) Each part has a few variants (for example: Gears could be of type: single gear, multiple gear, synchronous gear etc)

With these items and their specific variants a user could select a few hundred assemblies

I am wondering that
- If the number of assemblies and the constituent items in those are known is there a super fast way to select a particular assembly?
- the simplest solution is to have 5-6 drop downs and let the user select each item variant and thus select assembly

Any other solution is welcome :)

Comment: Depends on the presentation. You could have a tree that expands to the variants. So you'd have gears, for example, then on-click it'd show the types of gears and so on. @ the same time provide a list with an image/desc. that gets filtered by the tree selections. It would first start with all gears, then be reduced to a more precise list up selection. Then the user just picks the actual assembly they want. ??

Comment: what's that `byte-order-mark` tag doing here? lol.